# Is there a way to call external script without inheritance of environment variables in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I've a script which defines some environment variables. I want to call external script but it conflicts with environment variables I define. As mentioned in official documentation: environment variables and their values are inherited by child sessions. So my question: Is there a way to call external script without inheritance of environment variables I defined?

I call external script by this way:

```bsh
& { cmd /c "<path_to_scrip>\MySuperScript.cmd" } *>&1 | Write-Log
```